# utf-8 encoding in perl/c++

Tags: c++, perl, utf-8

I wrote some Perl code to read the data from a file and process it and print it to browser.

Sample content:

`Delhi[##DELIM##]Delhi,National Capital Territory of India,\u0926\u093F\u0932\u094D\u0932\u0940 \u062F\u0647\u0644\u06CC \u0A26\u0A3F\u0A71\u0A32\u0A40[##DELIM##]Place,PopulatedPlace,Settlement,Place,_Feature[##DELIM##]Delhi is a metropolitan region in India that includes the national capital city, New Delhi. It is India's second-most-populous city after Mumbai, and the largest city in terms of area. With a population of 22\u00A0million in 2011, the city is the fourth-largest city in the world. The NCT and its urban region have been given the special status of National Capital Region (NCR) under the Constitution of India's 69th amendment act of 1991.[##DELIM##]http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Delhi_Montage.jpg/200px-Delhi_Montage.jpg[##DELIM##]AreaCode: +91 11[##NEWLINE##]HomePage: http://delhi.gov.in[##NEWLINE##]NickName: Dilli (Hindi: \u0926\u093F\u0932\u094D\u0932\u0940, Urdu: \u062F\u0650\u0644\u0651\u06CC, Punjabi: \u0A26\u0A3F\u0A71\u0A32\u0A40)[##DELIM##]`

I am splitting the content using the delimiter `[#DELIM#]` and printing different components like name, description and some other information to browser. This file contains some Unicode characters and the content is not being displayed properly in browser. How can I handle it in Perl or C++?

Comment: http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html

Comment: By converting the `\uXXXX` codes into `&#xXXXX;` codes? That should display in any browser.

Comment: @Medinoc: Nope, the result is different than expected!

Comment: @amon Thanks for the link. I will keep that in mind from next time onwards.